# Generalised Azure VMs: Add user configuration on initial start

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machine

I have successfully created a generalised VHD and created a new Azure Virtual Machine with it.

However, when you generalise the VM, it appears to lose all user settings.

What is the best approach to configuring user settings when the VM initially starts? Some of the user configuration I'd like to set is:

1. Add the VM to the Home or Work network for Internet connection
2. Add a desktop background
3. Remove the initial welcome pop-up with Internet Explorer.

I have read a lot about Windows Answer files (unattend.xml). Is this a viable way to go, or does Azure provide an easier route?

Comment: Do you want to add one user or multiple users?

Comment: @Walter - one user will suffice

Comment: I suggest you use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet) to create your VM. You could add a admin user.

Comment: You also could use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-user-image)

Comment: Hi, do you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @walter, thanks but the examples you sent through seem to be infrastructure based. I'm looking for somthing that is 'after you have the infrastructure'. Is there a template that includes configuring the registry for example? If not, what approach would you suggest for 'config on first boot'.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [custom script extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript). They enable you to run an externally hosted powershell script just after provisioning. I've used this in the past to perform initial registry config at first boot.

Another option is using a startup script (Edit group policy -> Windows settings ->Scripts (Startup/shutdown) -> Startup -> Powershell). This will run at **every** startup ordinarily, but you can do something like create an empty file as a flag to denote it's already been run and check this at the start of the script.